# Flutterfire Configure FormatException: Unexpected character

Tags: flutter, firebase

**Edit: Issue resolve! It seemed to be a problem on Firebase's end which solved itself!**

I'm trying to add firebase to my newly created Flutter project following this tutorial:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios

However, when I get to this step:

```
flutterfire configure
```

I get the following error:[image]

Do you guys have any idea what's causing this?

Thanks!

I looked around for solutions, tried re-installing everything, but sadly nothing works.

Comment: Did you try to configure directly the specific project ? by running `flutterfire configure --project=<your-project-id>` ?

Comment: @Baimam Boukar Yes I did. The result is the same.

Comment: Okay! I think running `flutter clean`,  before trying again will work!

Comment: @Baimam Boukar Doesn't seem to solve it. I appreciate your help! I contacted firebase for support!